# Laravel AJAX to controller and back with data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am making an AJAX call from a view:

```
function compareProducts() {
    var productIds = [];
    $('#compare-widget tbody tr').each(function(i, ele) {
        productIds[i] = $(ele).data('product-id');
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: 'product/compare',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
            productIds: productIds
        },
        success: function(result) {
        }
    });
}
```

which is triggering the controller:

```
public function compare(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::whereIn('id', $request->productIds)->get();
    return view('compare', compact('products'));
}
```

but it is not doing anything in browser directly. When I open chrome inspector I see a OK 200 code, and when I open triggered link there, it shows fine, but I am not able to trigger redirection with AJAX.

If I do a `window.location.href = "compare";` I get redirected to right page, but I no longer have access to `$products`

Comment: refresh your view using javascript in the `success` callback. submit ajax tu controller is just to store a data

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. If you want to redirect after ajax call you will need to explicitly do this with javascript. Basically hooking something like `window.location.href = url` on `success` event.

Comment: I wrote that in description. If I do a href on success I can't fetch data from ID's and return them the way the controller does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the products to the `session` and redirect to the compare page, that way you would have access to the `products` when you redirect to the compare page

```
public function compare(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::whereIn('id', $request->productIds)->get();

    session(['products' => $products]);

    return url('compare');
}
```

and in your success callback you could redirect to the compare page

```
success: function (result) {
    window.location.href = result;
}
```

and in your `compare` view access the products from the session

```
{{ session('products') }}
```